# How to avoid re-rendering when passing event handlers to nested functional components

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a simple functional component that renders many other functional components depending on a filter field. `HomeView` is the parent functional component, which uses state to handle `DomainCard` (the child functional component) filtering:

```js
const HomeView = props => {
  // domains
  const domains = useSelector(state => state.domains)
  const [nameFilter, setNameFilter] = useState('')

  const goToDomainDetailView = id => {
    history.push(config.urls.domainLocal.replace(':id', id))
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: '2rem', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
        <Input
          icon='search'
          placeholder='Search domain'
          onChange={(e, { value }) => setNameFilter(value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        {domains.data
          .filter(domain => !nameFilter || domain.name.toLowerCase().includes(nameFilter.toLowerCase()))
          .map((domain, idx) => (
            <div key={idx}>
                <DomainCard
                  fluid
                  raised
                  onClick={goToDomainDetailView}
                  id={domain.id}
                  title={domain.name}
                  image={DomainAutomotiveImage}
                />
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now what happens here, is that while filtering, the components (`DomainCard`) which are already shown, re-renders, even if memoizing them. That's because the `HomeView` component itself re-renders due to its state change, and being a functional component, the `goToDomainDetailView` function is re-defined and changes from previous commit.

So the only thing that came to my mind was to define the `goToDomainDetailView` outside of the component:

```js
const goToDomainDetailView = id => {
  history.push(config.urls.domainLocal.replace(':id', id))
}

const HomeView = props => {
  // domains
  const domains = useSelector(state => state.domains)
  const [nameFilter, setNameFilter] = useState('')

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ marginTop: '2rem', marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
        <Input
          icon='search'
          placeholder='Search domain'
          onChange={(e, { value }) => setNameFilter(value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        {domains.data
          .filter(domain => !nameFilter || domain.name.toLowerCase().includes(nameFilter.toLowerCase()))
          .map((domain, idx) => (
            <div key={idx}>
                <DomainCard
                  fluid
                  raised
                  onClick={goToDomainDetailView}
                  id={domain.id}
                  title={domain.name}
                  image={DomainAutomotiveImage}
                />
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Now, this stuff works, in this case.

But it works because the `goToDomainDetailView` function does not rely on the component props or on the Redux dispatch function, for example. If that was the case, I simply cannot move the function outside, and the only other way I imagine to avoid re-rendering is to transform the `HomeView` component in a class Component, so that the `goToDomainDetailView` function can be defined as a class method, though not changing in case of re-rendering.

So the questions are:

- Are my assumptions correct?
- How do you handle this common cases?
- Which is in your opinion the proper way to use nested functional components with state and avoid  re-rendering of all functional child components (for example using the second argument of `React.memo` and avoiding re-rendering if only the handler function ref changes?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `useCallback()` hook to memoize callbacks:

```js
...
const somePropDependantCallback = useCallback(
  id => console.log(id, someProp),
  [ someProp ]
);
```

Comment: yeah, that's the answer, I missed `useCallback`, thanks